# PHP e MySQL, como milhares de conexões são processadas ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php, mysql

Utilizando o PHP e MySQL como exemplo, vamos supor que existem 1000 conexões (clientes) acessando o site e utilizando funções que abrem conexão com o MySQL e fazem consultas. Como o PHP e MySQL processam tantas conexões e consultas ao mesmo tempo?

Se existem 1000 clientes conectados no site fazendo requisições ao MySQL, então existem 1000 conexões MySQL?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **P:** *"Se existem 1000 clientes conectados no site fazendo requisições ao MySQL, então existem 1000 conexões MySQL?"*

> **R:** Somente se os 1000 iniciarem exatamente ao mesmo tempo uma navegação nas páginas que usam conexão com o DB. Depois de carregada a página na tela, a conexão já encerrou.

**Normalmente** as conexões são feitas no início do script que serve a página, e fechadas logo em seguida. É normal você ter 1000 pessoas usando o seu site simultaneamente, mas na prática acontecendo apenas 15 ou 20 conexões simultâneas. O tempo gasto por quem navega é muito maior na visualização e leitura das páginas do que clicando nos links e carregando dados, e é muito improvável que esses cliques aconteçam ao mesmo tempo com frequência.

Digo normalmente, pois o pesadelo dos *hosts* de sites é a tal da conexão persistente, que é aberta num script e mantida em algum objeto de sessão para que outras páginas a usem. É uma prática não recomendada, pois prejudica a performance de todas as aplicações do servidor do DB, mas ainda é possível fazer em muitos hosts.

### E se eu precisar realmente de muitas conexões simultâneas?

Existem muitas técnicas para se fazer a distribuição de carga, quando a aplicação demanda muitos acessos simultâneos, mas aí não estamos falando de apenas 1000 conexões simultâneas. Pode colocar mais alguns zeros neste número.

Eis algumas bem comuns:

- **Espelhamento / replicação da base de dados**

  Neste caso, você tem vários servidores de DB, e quando altera algo no principal, estes dados são copiados para os slaves. A vantagem deste método é que você divide os clientes por vários servidores, efetivamente multiplicando a capacidade pelo número de instâncias servindo o DB. Desvantagem: o espaço de armazenagem é proporcional ao número de servidores.
- **Distribuição de dados**

  Usando técnicas como map/reduce,  você tem os dados distribuidos em várias máquinas, mas sem o espelhamento. Parte fica numa máquina, parte fica em outra, e sua consulta é mandada para vários lugares ao mesmo tempo, mas só o "pai da criança" devolve a resposta. Neste caso, você precisa já de um projeto mais avançado de gerenciamento de dados. A vantagem deste método é que você não ocupa o espaço com dados redundantes. A desvantagem é a maior complexidade na arquitetura. Exemplo: Google.
- **Caches / buffers**

  Você pode reter parte dos dados na aplicação, para não fazer consultas no servidor a todo momento. Um exemplo deste caso seria uma paginação de dados onde você carrega os dados e mantém no cache da aplicação, ou mesmo no browser, assim, quando a pessoa avança ou volta páginas, os dados não precisam ser recarregados. Exemplo: listagem de domínios de um usuário do Registro.br - seus domínios são carregados num único JSON, e quando você avança ou volta página, só está mudando a visualização, e não recarregando os dados - Notar que isto também é uma espécie de *early loading*, veja a seguir.
- **Predição / *early loading***

  Este caso é uma faca de dois gumes. Aqui você ganha performance, mas com o risco de carregar dados desnecessariamente. A técnica consiste em carregar mais dados do que precisa, pra quando a pessoa avançar para a página seguinte, ou rolar uma listagem, os dados já estarem lá. O problema neste caso é que você geralmente está sempre carregando mais dados do que necessita. A vantagem é que você fez isso ocupando o tempo em que o usuário está analisando os dados anteriores.

Comment: Lembrando que a técnica de `Cache / buffer` também pode ser uma faca de dois gumes, já que ao trazer um bloco inteiro de dados (para paginação, por exemplo) assume-se que o usuário irá consumir todo esse bloco, o que não necessariamente é verdade.

Comment: @Kazzkiq na verdade acho que eu peguei um exemplo ruim, pq o caso do registro.br é um misto de cache com predição, se for ver. Vou pensar melhor, e no próximo edit ponho um cache puro de exemplo.

Comment: Eu achei o exemplo para paginação bom, é uma coisa realmente útil, mas falando mais na pratica, pode ser um tiro no pé. Olha a Globo.com por exemplo, os comentários do site vem todos juntos em um bloco JSON. Ai você pega notícias com até 10.000 comentários e imagina a trabalheira que dá pro banco trazer isso tudo, quando com certeza os usuários não lerão nem 10% disso. É claro que é um exemplo extremo e eles devem ter *n* formas de otimizar as requisições, mas ainda vale a pena estudar cada caso antes de usar essa solução. Enfim, só um pequeno complemento para esta ótima resposta!

Comment: @Kazzkiq concordo, só que eu acho que a paginação eu devia ter posto no exemplo de baixo, que é mais o caso. Do cache, teria que ser uma paginação já vista, e não carregar a seguinte (como globo e registro.br). O cache seria na verdade manter os dados que ja foram vistos, e não necessariamente carregar os seguintes (assim como um histórico de navegador). Mas vou pensar melhor e mexer só quando achar exemplos bem claros.

Answer (score 7):

> Se existem 1000 clientes conectados no site fazendo requisições ao MySQL, então existem 1000 conexões MySQL?

Não necessariamente. Mesmo que seu servidor de banco de dados suporte mil conexões simultâneamente fazendo requests, seria um grande desperdício de recursos se estes requests estivessem pedindo dados iguais.

Por exemplo, se seu site recebe 1000 requisições de dados durante um certo período de tempo, é provável que muitas requisições diferentes estejam pedindo os mesmos dados. É ainda bastante provável que durante esse certo período de tempo estes dados não tenham sido modificados.
Considerando isso, torna-se um desperdício de recursos, consultar o banco procurando algo já préviamente consultado e que não foi alterado.
A solução para esse tipo de situação é o [*caching*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache) dos dados.

Um servidor de banco de dados com *caching* implantado, armazena em memória a resposta de cada nova consulta a medida que são requisitadas, para que uma futura requisição semelhante não preciso ir até o banco de dados buscar o dado. O dado já já estará disponível em memória e uma nova consulta somente acontece se um dado previamente consultado foi modificado ou se ele não foi ainda previamente consultado e por isso não está na memória, não está no *cache*.

Portanto, num servidor com sistema de *caching* implantado, 1000 requisições significam 1000 consultas somente se elas pedirem por dados diferentes.

Comment: O MySQL já vem com essa técnica de caching habilitada por padrão?

Comment: Depende, você pode verificar com a consulta:
    mysql> show variables like 'have_query_cache';
Mais informações (em inglês): http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/speed-up-your-web-site-with-mysql-query-caching/

Answer (score 5):

Resposta curta: Depende muito da estrutura, tal como a largura de banda, quantidade de RAM entre outros fatores.

O número máximo de conexões que o MySQL pode suportar depende da qualidade da biblioteca de threads numa plataforma, a quantidade de RAM disponível, a quantidade de RAM que é utilizada para cada conexão, a carga de trabalho de cada conexão, e o tempo de resposta desejado.

Linux ou Solaris devem ser capazes de suportar algo entre *500~1000* conexões simultâneas rotineiramente e até 10.000 conexões, se você tem muitos gigabytes de RAM disponíveis e a carga de trabalho de cada um é baixo ou o tempo de resposta pouco exigente.

[`MySql - Muitas Conexões`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/too-many-connections.html)

Em relação ao **PHP**, acredito que não há um limite, você pode abrir *n* conexões, entretanto que, o servidor do banco de dados e [servidor de aplicativos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_de_aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) suportarem.

Comment: Se exceder esses números, então as conexões e consultas entram em um tipo de fila? Tipo "thread blocking" I/O?

Comment: @GustavoPiucco Acredito que não, é devolvido um erro, algo como isso `Too many connections` veja essa [imagem](https://nyjoomla.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/phpbbjoomla.jpg) Para resolver um problema como esse, seria necessário manipular a variável [`max_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) para setar a quantidade máxima de conexões.

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei aqui, o MySQL cria 1 thread para cada conexão e dentro de cada conexão 1 thread para cada consulta. Que estranho, não seria melhor se operasse com um numero minimo de threads (non-blocking I/O) igual é nos servidores que precisam suportar milhares de conexões simultâneas? Uma vez li que usar mais que 10 threads por aplicação é uma técnica/pratica impropria.

Comment: Você está correto, as threads criadas que são associadas a conexão do cliente são criadas apenas quando é preciso. Um bom texto para ler sobre o assunto é esse [Como o MySQL Utiliza Threads para conexões de cliente](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-threads.html).