# Capacidade de requisições / consultas usando PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um projeto e me falta um pouco de conhecimento teórico e prático sobre o operacional, os requisitos e a capacidade de resposta do PHP + MySQL.

Estou criando a API do projeto inicialmente em PHP e nela haverá um long pooling que verificará as alterações realizadas no servidor e repassará imediatamente ao cliente caso haja alguma mudança. Estou pensando em realizar essa verificação de 1 em 1 segundo, ou seja, uma consulta ao DB a cada segundo para cada cliente conectado.

Essas solicitações são as que mais vão exigir do sistema, porém, além delas haverá outras pequenas consultas esporádicas. Tendo esse cenário em vista, pensei em iniciar uma hospedagem mais simples e ir progredindo com os upgrades de hardware de acordo com que o projeto demante, porém, estou em dúvida até onde conseguiria ir usando PHP + MySQL. Sei que pode ser difícil fazer uma estimativa assim, sem nada concreto e sem mais detalhes do projeto, mas, será que consigo manter uns 100, 200, 500 clientes (consultas por segundo) com segurança?

Obs: Essas consultas ao DB (1 por segundo para cada cliente) serão pequenas e indexadas, retornando provavelmente um único campo com um JSON para atualizar o cliente, se necessário.

Comment: Teria que ver o que vai usar de tecnologia. Se usar o PHP "puro", evitando bobeiras desnecessárias como OOP (afinal, é uma linguagem de script para requisições avulsas que não mantém estado) é uma coisa, se enfiar esses frameworks da moda e as boas práticas que a molecadinha que se aventura na área sem preparo (infelizmente tá virando a maioria) gosta, já precisa de muito mais máquina. Não sei se isso dá pra tratar objetivamente no escopo do site, talvez [o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)  fosse mais adequado, já que seus pontos permitem.

Comment: Só pra constar, 500 consultas por segundo é um volume bem baixo de requisições, salvo alguma coisa fora do normal, não é pra ter problemas. Mais detalhes aqui: [PHP e MySQL, como milhares de conexões são processadas ao mesmo tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16957/70)

Comment: Estou usando o PHP puro, confesso que receoso em deixar alguma coisa passar, principalmente por XSS e Injection, mas, aprender a usar um framework iria me tomar muito tempo para domina-lo e atrasaria consideravelmente o projeto, tendo em vista que é algo que fiz para mim e resolvi compartilhar com outras pessoas que por ventura precisem. Mas é frustrante como o php pendeu para o lado do framework, esses dias estava procurando implementar autenticação em 2 fatores mas só achei material para laravel, code ignate e etc...

Comment: Fique sossegado, pq o pessoal que fala que FW evita isso é quase terraplanista. Inclusive é uma falácia que os fãs de um bem famoso repetem na esperança de virar verdade. Tanto que é sempre gente desqualificada que propaga isso. Se a pessoa não entende fundamentos, vai fazer besteira com ou sem FW. Só de ter essas preocupações, em vez de comprar as baboseiras cegamente, você já demonstra estar num caminho melhor que a grande maioria deles. Estude intensamente sempre, de cabeça aberta. Esse é o jeito de minimizar problemas, e ao mesmo tempo de ter soluções profissionais se alguns acontecerem.

Comment: Acho engraçado, o PHP+Mysql foi o porto seguro por anos e anos e de repente, começou a aparecer tecnologias mais rápidas, o que é ótimo, mas, não faz o PHP ser ruim e muitas pessoas não entendem isso. Lembro de uma comparação entre PHP e NODEJS em que o Node respondia digamos que 300k de solicitações por segundo e o PHP digamos que 150K, aí o pessoal falando que PHP era lento, caramba, 150K/segundo é muita coisa, vai ser mais que o suficiente para muitos e muitos casos. Infelizmente as pessoas ficam alienadas a certas propagandas ao invés de focar no que realmente precisa para seu projeto .

Comment: Para finalizar creio então que não deverei ter problemas com as solicitações PHP + MySQL, vou me focar em realizar a construção do ambiente de produção e no aperfeiçoamento do que já tenho. Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos @Bacco, fico mais tranquilo em poder atrasar um pouco a substituição do MySQL pelo Redis (se realmente acabar havendo a necessidade) nesse caso em específico. Obrigado novamente.